# Postgres : Group by two columns - group by includes all unique combinations with 0 for null counts

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have a single table called cases as below

```
os      device      event_time
Android     Mobile      <Tstamp>
Android     Tablet      <Tstamp>
Windows     PC          <Tstamp>
Linux       PC          <Tstamp>
```

I want an output such as below:

```
os         device    events_count
Android    Mobile      10
Android    Tablet      22
Android    PC          0
Windows    Mobile      0
Windows    Tablet      0
Windows    PC          40
Linux      Mobile      0
Linux      Tablet      0
Linux      PC          21
```

The original table does not contain any row with (Android, PC), (Windows, Mobile), etc combinations but I seek the output to have these rows with zero count. The normal group by query doesn't give me those probably because the original table doesn't have these combinations at all.

```
select os, device, count(event_time)
from cases
group by os, device;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First select all OS / device combinations, then outer join your table again:

```
select o.os, d.device, count(e.events_count)
from (select distinct os from events) o
cross join (select distinct device from events) d
left join events e on e.os = o.os and e.device = d.device
group by o.os, d.device
order by o.os, d.device;
```

(For such data you'd usually have an OS table and a device table, though. You'd cross join these and then outer join your event table.)

Comment: Thanks. I do not have a separate 'mytable' containing all the possible unique combinations of os and device. Are you suggesting I'll need that? I need all the *possible unique* combinations of the values in os and device columns in my output.

Comment: No usually you'd have one table containing all OS. Then another table with all devices. You may have a third table containing all allowed combinations, but if any combination is allowed, such table doesn't make any sense. And then you'd have your events table, containing `os_id` (referencing a record in the OS table), `device_id` (referencing a record in the device table) and `event_time`.

Comment: Ok. I do not have separate table for os and device because I just need os and device name. Anyways, I modified your query to work with single events table as below:                                                                                                           `select devs.os, devs.device, count(e.events_count)
from (select a.os, b.device from (select distinct os from events) a, (select distinct device from events) b) devs
left join events e on e.os = devs.os and e.device = devs.device
group by devs.os, devs.device
order by devs.os, devs.device;`

Comment: The OS and device tables would be there to ensure data integrity. E.g. in order to avoid typos. With an OS table containing 'Android', 'Windows', and 'Linux' you would avoid entries with 'Andiod' or 'Windos'. Another argument is that If someday there is a new Windows and you want to rename 'Windows' to 'Windows (version 10 and older)' you'd do this in one place and not in every single record in your database where the OS is used.

Comment: You were right to correct my query. I must have been tired :-) Of course you must select distinct OS and cross join these with distinct devices anyway. But you are using a join syntax that we used in the 1980s, before it was made redundant in 1992 by ANSI joins. Then, when using alias names, use mnemonic ones. `a` and `b` say nothing. Make this `o` for OS and `d` for device or the like. I've updated my query.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `cross join`

```
select t.os, t.device, count(c.os)
from 
(
  select os, device
  from
  (
    select distinct os from cases
  ) t1
  cross join 
  (
    select distinct device from cases
  ) t2
) t 
left join cases c on t.os = c.os and 
                     t.device = c.device
group by t.os, t.device
```

Comment: You are right; of course we need a cross join of OS and devices. I don't know why I didn't write my query accordingly when I even mentioned that this must be done. Must have been tired ;-)